# Getting the next value of a list within a loop

Tags: python, list

I have the following lists:

```
elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f']
```

and

```
y = ['c','d']
```

I want to code:

```
for i in elements:

    if i in y: do something

    elif the next element after i is in y: do something
```

Essentially, if `i` is iterating over `'b'` in `elements` , I want the loop to "see" that `'c'` is going to come next, and I'm not sure how to make that into an IF condition.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens if `i in y` but `i` is the last element of `y`?

Comment: No idea, perhaps returns null? I thought of that too. But the way I want to use it, I'll not run into that problem. Good question nonetheless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the index in the loop instead:

```
for index in range(len(elements)):
    if elements[index] in y:
        # do something
    elif index < len(elements) - 1 and elements[index + 1] in y:
        # do something else
```

Of course, you can also do this with `enumerate` (although I don't like mixing indices and item enumeration):

```
for index, element in enumerate(elements):
    if element in y:
        # do something
    elif index < len(elements) - 1 and elements[index + 1] in y:
        # do something else
```

Note that both times we need to check that `index < len(elements) - 1` because otherwise `elements[index + 1]` fails

#### Edit

As @PadraicCunningham points out in the comments, you can also use `enumerate` on `elements[:-1]` (everything except the last item) to make the index check unnecessary. Beware, however, that the first `if` part will never be entered for the last item with that option:

```
for index, element in enumerate(elements[:-1]):
    if element in y:
        # do something
    elif elements[index + 1] in y:
        # do something else
```

Comment: `enumerate(elements[:-1])` will work, you have a check for the length each time which is not needed

Answer (score 4):

You can always use `enumerate` to get the current index of `i`.  Then the next element is `elements[index+1]`.

```
for index, i in enumerate(elements[:-1]):

    if i in y: do something

    elif elements[index+1] in y: do something
```

Comment: If element i is the last element this is going to raise an IndexError.

Comment: @RickardSjogren: Fixed the issue.

Comment: why not just iterate over `elements[:-1]`, you have an unnecessary check for the length each time

Answer (score 1):

The following might give you an idea:

```
for this, next in zip(elements[:-1], elements[1:]):
   print this, next  # do your thing instead
```

Comment: This one is my favorite method, very simple. Thanks a bunch. I now learned about the zip() function

Comment: why not `zip(elements, elements[1:])`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Slightly more explicit, but either would work.